# CKEditor adding text in the tag which is closed

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I've created a custom plugin in CKEditor. It is working fine. The role of the plugin is to add a tooltip to the selected text. According to my code, the text is getting wrapped with the  tag.

The issue is, when I select the last word and add a tooltip, it will be wrapped by span. Now when I add anything after it, it automatically gets added in my  tag. Whereas it should not be added in the  tag.

To reproduce this, you can check with the bold feature. Select the last word and Bold it. Then you can write anything and it comes in bold. The text you write will be added in the  tag automatically.

In my case, it should not be added to the tag.

Comment: I think there's little to nothing you can do, unless you change the whole behavior of CKEditor regarding to those markings. You yourself have found that this happens with bold feature. If you type right after the formatting you've just applied to the text block, then it will extend the formatted block with the newly typed text. If you wanted to begin a new word without the formatting, then you should leave a whitespace after the text to be formatted and select until the last character before it. Maybe even that won't be enough, maybe you need to add a letter after the whitespace.

Comment: Even MS Word behaves like that…

Comment: I agree with you @Alexandre. But when clicking on the bold button, it is adding some zero-width white space. I want to achieve that. Do you have any idea about it?